# CensoredWriter cw = new CensoredWriter(System.out, "whine|whining");

Tags: java

I am using Dr.Java to do this constructor. When i typed following in the interactions box

```
CensoredWriter cw = new CensoredWriter(System.out, "whine|whining");

cw.print("No whining")
```

It returns "No whining", but the right answer should be "No %!^*#@" according to my constructor. What is the problem here?

```
public class CensoredWriter extends PrintWriter {

    String censored;

    public CensoredWriter(OutputStream o, String c) {
        super(o);
        this.censored = c;
    }

    public CensoredWriter(File f, String c) throws Exception {
        super(f);
        this.censored = c;
    }

    public CensoredWriter(String s, String c) throws Exception {
        super(s);
        this.censored = c;
    }

    public String transform(String s) {
        String a = s.replace(censored, "%!^*#@");
        return a;
    }

    @Override
    public void print(String s) {
        transform(s);
        super.print(s);
        flush();

    }

    @Override
    public void println(String s) {
        print(s);
        flush();
    }
}
```

Comment: Look at what your `print` method does. It transforms the string, doesn't use the transformed string for anything, then prints the original string, then flushes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are actually two problems.

- `replace` will only replace a full string match.  [`replaceAll`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) actually allows you to use a regular experssion.
- You don't store the result of your `transform` call in the `print` method, so it falls on the floor.  I'd personally inline the call anyway, since you're going to get a new String back anyhow:

  ```
  @Override
  public void print(String s) {
      super.print(transform(s));
      flush();
  }
  ```

Comment: are there any places I need to put a close()?

Comment: I doubt it.  Don't see why you'd need to close it, necessarily.

Answer (score 1):

`String.replace()` doesn't do patterns. You've set `cw.censored` to the string `"whine|whining"`, so it'll only replace that entire string, not just parts of it.

Additionally, you're not using the return value of the `transform()` function. It doesn't (and can't!) modify the string in place. Try `super.print(transform(s))`.

Comment: `replaceAll`, on the other hand, would do patterns.

Comment: are there any places I need to put a close()?